# How to use startswith in loc for a dataframe ? Or merger dataframe columns ignoring None?

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, startswith

is there a way to use startswith in a loc function to assign a column value to an other column based on the first column value ?

I've tried :

```
inventory_at_date.loc[inventory_at_date["asset_class"].str.contains('Cash'), "security_class"] = inventory_at_date["asset_class"]
```

but I get

```
ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values
```

Ex :
Column "asset class" contains

```
0    Cash EUR
1        None
2        None
3        None
4        None
5        None
```

Column "security class" contains

```
0        None
1        Equity
2        Equity
3        Equity
4        Equity
5        Equity
```

Result wanted in "security class" column:

```
0        Cash EUR
1        Equity
2        Equity
3        Equity
4        Equity
5        Equity
```

Is there better way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a merger type of function. You can try using `combine_first`.

```
df['security class'] = df['asset class'].combine_first(df['security class'])
```

Comment: Works fine ! Thanks. Will settle for this one as it limits imports.